# Kafka Broker ReplicaFetcherThread uses 100% CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

We have 6 brokers running on AWS EC2 (i3.large with 4vcpu), with approx 1000 partitions assigned to each of them. If we replace a broker (same broker ID), with zero data - and replication starts - regardless of how many num.replica.fetchers, we set (have tried 1-5) - the fetcher threads are always maxing out CPU. Currently we are on Confluent 5.3.2 open source.

```
broker.rack=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
broker.id=$KB_BROKER_ID
listeners=PLAINTEXT://$KB_ENIIP:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://$KB_ENIIP:9092
auto.create.topics.enable=false
default.replication.factor=3
inter.broker.protocol.version=2.3
log.dirs=$KB_LOGDIRDATA
log.message.format.version=2.3
log.roll.hours=24
log.retention.hours=48
log.segment.bytes=100000000
min.insync.replicas=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=4
offsets.retention.minutes=10080
num.network.threads=16
num.io.threads=20
socket.send.buffer.bytes=-1
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=-1
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=10000
num.partitions=6
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=1000000
zookeeper.connect=$ZK_CONN
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=10000
message.max.bytes=5242880
replica.fetch.max.bytes=5242880
replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=5242880
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=5242880
num.replica.fetchers=2
confluent.support.metrics.enable=false




      PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6913 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 R 87.5 17.7  13:11.24 ReplicaFetcherT
 6916 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 R 81.2 17.7   8:34.31 ReplicaFetcherT
 6929 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 R 81.2 17.7   8:55.83 ReplicaFetcherT
 6930 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 R 68.8 17.7   8:04.13 ReplicaFetcherT
 6918 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 S 12.5 17.7   0:41.58 ReplicaFetcherT
 6919 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 S 12.5 17.7   3:13.76 ReplicaFetcherT
 6927 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 S 12.5 17.7   5:05.56 ReplicaFetcherT
 6931 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 R  6.2 17.7   7:30.61 ReplicaFetcherT
 6777 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 S  0.0 17.7   0:00.00 java
 6807 kafka     20   0   66.2g   5.3g  64128 S  0.0 17.7   0:02.69 java
```

1. Does anyone know why this might be occurring ? (is this by design ?)
2. Is it possible to limit CPU usage of the replicathreads ?
3. Is the only possible solution, to throw more CPU at the issue ? I did test an instance with 8vcpu, however the fetcher threads still wanted to consume all CPU.
4. Can setting more num.io.threads and num.network.threads actually increase CPU usage ?

Comment: What instance types are you using? What other configs did you set? What other metrics are you looking at? Tried rolling restart?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, i3.large. Entire server.properties has been updated. I'm also looking at request handler  and net handler average idle time percentage. When this is occurring, these metrics are down to 0.

Comment: I would think either your disks are bad, or tweaking num.replica.fetchers=2 and num.io.threads=20... Also, you cannot curl within a property file

Comment: As mentioned, tweaking the replica fetches had no effect on CPU. It was at 100% regardless. And yes, you can dynamically generate this with CURL , as my server properties is created by another script.

Comment: I would throw more cpu at it as a test. It can help diagnose, even if you don't want to run a larger instance type long term.

Comment: @RodrigoM Thanks, but yes - i tried this - and the fetcher threads still want to consume all CPU.